# "attempts to access secure API" error in Blackberry

Tags: api, blackberry

When I install an .alx file on my Blackberry 9530, I get an error "attempts to access secure API"   However, I already signed this application successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 types of signatures that might be required: RBB, RCR, RRT. I'm not sure what each of those means but you need to use all of them. I think you might have installed only one of them and that's why the installation fails.

Comment: thanx Mugur but i have install all .but how can we check that it properly install or not ?

Comment: I use the SignatureTool to sign my applications. When you do that, for each .cod file you will see a status for the signature. It should either be Not Signed or Not Required. After you sign the application(hit the Request button and enter your keys password), all the Not Signed Statuses should turn to Signed.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this very frustrating problem.

Make sure that you are compiling your project with the same JRE that is in use on your device. I was using JRE 7.1.0 and didn't have any problems with most projects, but some would give the "attempts to access secure API" error on my 5.0.0 device. Compiling for 5.0.0 solved the problem.

To change which JRE you're using in your project, right-click "JRE System Library" in your project, and select Properties. Select your desired JRE from the dropdown menu. If the required JRE isn't installed, follow the directions on the BlackBerry site (listed below) to download it.

It looks like the package wouldn't get signed by RRT in 7.1.0, but does in 5.0.0.

I found the solution [here](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/246927-signed-application-error-module-go-attempts-access-secure-api.html), and you can find instructions to download more JREs [here](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

Can you also sign a `jar /jad` combination - I am Using Netbeans.

The `jad` loads fine in the Blackberry - and simple apps can run.  The conversion to `cod` is a hassle - and often produces unusable `.cod` files.