# Blackberry Application Signing, Is it required?

Tags: windows, eclipse, blackberry, signing

I have created a simple native application using Blackberry API's.

Application contains only a Login Form and Alert.
The applicaiton runs on simulator but while running on the device (9300 BB OS 6.0) it gives error "applicaiton attempts" to access secure API.

Is simple form under "Secure" API's.

Comment: I got it working now. I guess it (or I) was not sighing right way using eclipse plugin. I signed it using sigtool coming with BB JDE. and it is working fine on device now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are APIs which requires to be signed from RIM to use them on real devices. If you look at the API docs, you can see Category Signed. That indicates you need to sign your application.

To get the signing keys for free from [here](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/) and you can sign your applications. See related StackOverflow question: [“attempts to access secure API” error in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377457/attempts-to-access-secure-api-error-in-blackberry)

Answer (score 1):

Almost every application, even basic ones, will require signing to be used on a real device. Anything that touches the native functionality of the phone or uses non-standard Java methods requires a signature.

You can get your signing keys for free [from here](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/). Be prepared for a couple dozen emails every time you sign an application though.

Comment: My question was, is even simple form with two labels, two text fields and a button will require the signing.

Comment: Technically Labels, Buttons, and TextFields themselves don't require signing. Are you connecting to a network?

Comment: No, I am not. Now even I got the signing file from Blackberry. I signed the application. Still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

TRedman already gave the link to the [order form](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/) (you'll need a credit card, but it's still free).

As for the signing, yes, it's pretty much required to do anything useful with the actual device. In my opinion the API is borderline paranoid, even things like asking for the display dimensions (width and height) require signing. The signing itself is a fairly simple process (at least with the Eclipse-plugin), [here](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/blackberrydev/secure-development-of-blackberry-applications/howto-sign-a-blackberry-java-application/)'s some instructions. Sometimes the signing servers are down (for up to several hours), http://isthesigningserverdown.com/ is your friend.

Also, I'd suggest to get the signing emails sent to some mailbox with no other use. Depending on the application size, you can get huge amount of email. If (and when) you want to distribute your application to actual device, the application is split into many small files, and each is signed separately. This is done every time, even if you change only one line of code. For each signed file, you'll get a separate email (or maybe up to three emails, there's separate signing for RRT, RBB and RCR for each file). My manager (whose mail was used to get the signing keys) had 12,000 signing emails awaiting in his inbox from a single project, when he was away for two weeks. When asked if the email could be changed, we were told that it can't be changed, and we'd need to order new keys.

Comment: The emails are beyond annoying, but I just put a filter in my inbox so I never have to see them.